# Хранение целой и дробной части в int

Tags: c#, golang, int, byte

На просторах интернетов услышал от юзера, что можно хранить целую и дробную части (например 21,3 доллара) в первых двух байтах и последних двух байтах четырёхбайтного int соответственно. (Я понимаю, что можно умножить число на 100 и когда оно может нам понадобиться, можно делить его на 100, чтобы вытащить целую и дробную части, но меня интересует именно то, как можно хранить их в первых и последних двух байтах)

Вопрос: как это сделать в каком-нибудь Golang или C#?

Comment: Сделать то можно, а смысл в этом какой? Какая задача решается? В C# есть тип `decimal`, в котором всё хранится как надо и вычисляется без потерь точности, во всяком случае для валют он вполне подходит

Comment: Можно как услышал, но тогда получится только хранить, а для операций придётся разделять на две части, выполнять операцию и опять соединять. Намного лучше хранить число в центах (213) или в сотых цента (21300). В таком случае вся арифметика работает как есть, можно хранить и передавать в этом виде, и нужно просто форматировать для вывода на экран.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что так лучше. Мне просто интересна сама реализация, как можно хранить эти части в первых и последних байтах int. Вот просто хочется для общего кругозора и всё тут :)

Comment: `int combined = xxx; int dollars = (combined >> 16) & 0xFFFF; int cents = combined & 0xFFFF;`

Comment: `int combined = ((dollars & 0xFFFF) << 16) | (cents & 0xFFFF)`

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите свой ответ в ответы, а не комментарий. Я отмечу его, как решающий мой вопрос. Спасибо :)

Comment: В C# можно заюзать [StructLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute?view=net-7.0). В языках C/C++ используется [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union)

Comment: Может, вы слышали про [BCD](http://av-assembler.ru/asm/afd/bcd.htm)? (первая ссылка, которая попалась)